# how can I safely import files to sql server in ssis while new files are actively being written to the source directory?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need to import many xml files into sql server every day. I was thinking of running a for each loop container every few minutes to import the files to the db table and then move them to another directory, but sometimes over a dozen new files are written to the source folder every minute. Is it going to be an issue if the Package tries to loop through the folder at the exact moment new files are being written to the folder? If so, how can I work around this?

Comment: SSIS will normally try to open the file for editting when reading, so if the text file is being written to SSIS will likely fail.

Comment: We usually move the files to a new folder that we control.  When done we move them to another folder.  We then always know what is waiting, what is in progress and what has completed.  As another method, we rename files to accomplish the same control

Comment: Is this also true for a file system task in ssis? Meaning will I have to resort to a method outside of ssis entirely for moving the files to a staging folder?

Comment: if your asking its a script task then answer to that is YES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the files in a script task and attempt to move them to a separate "ReadyToProcess" folder in a try/catch.  Catch the IOException if the file is in use by another process, and continue on to the next file.  The skipped file will be picked up on the next run.  Then loop over the files in "ReadyToProcess" to read them into the database.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you know what files are finished writing and what files are still being modified which makes things a little easier. It is important to remember: if your SSIS task tries to open a file this currently being modified or used by another process the SSIS package will fail.

You can work around this by using a script task to generate a list of files in your source folder at a point in time and use a for or foreach loop to only fetch the files that are in the generated list. This would be in contrast to fetching everything that's in your source folders, as your post implies.

Other solutions would be to batch your incoming files and offset the package execution time so there isn't a risk of the file being exported to SQL as it's imported into your source folder.

For instance, loading your source documents in batches every 30 minutes: 1:00, 1:30, 2...

and execute your SSIS task every 30 minutes, but offset from the batch by 15 minutes: 1:15, 1:45, 2:15...

Lastly, if possible, run your SSIS package at a period where there will be no new files written to your source folder. While not always possible, if you knew there wouldn't be any new documents coming in at 2AM that'd be the best time to scheudle your SSIS package.